# thread building blocks and graphical processing unit

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, nvidia, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

can we execute thread building blocks threads on a Nvidia graphical processing unit? I want to have multiple threads for my tbb code so what should be optimum number for the same and can i use gpu threads instead of cpu threads?

Answer (score 2):

TBB use threads provided by an operation system. If you want to use some kind of GPU accelerators you can try to use [streaming_node](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/overview.html) ([Documentation](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB)). It could help you to simplify using OpenCL(for example) for computation.

Streaming_node is a part of [TBB Flow graph](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB#reference/flow_graph.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, TBB is not supported for Nvidia GPUs. But CUDA and Thrust are. These provide a first-class programming environment, and Thrust provides easy-to-use parallel primitives, as does TBB.